# In R, How do you extract multiple matched terms as string and match if TRUE with Regex or Grep?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I'm still a beginner in R. I need help with some code that searches a vector for terms in a list and returns TRUE. If TRUE, return a string of matched terms.

I have it set to tell me if terms match and return the first matched term but I'm not sure how to get the rest of the matched terms.

In the attached code, I have my Desired_Output and the imperfect Final_Output.

```
#create dataset of 2 columns/vectors. 1st column is "Job Title", 2nd column is "Work Experience"
'Work Experience' <- c("cooked food; cleaned house; made beds", "analyzed data; identified gaps; used sql, python, and r", "used tableau to make dashboards for clients; applied advanced macro excel functions", "financial planning and strategy; consulted with leaders and clients")
'Job Title' <- c("dad", "research analyst", "business intelligence consultant", "finance consultant")
Job_Hist   <- data.frame(`Job Title`, `Work Experience`)

#create list of terms to search for in Job_Hist
Term_List <- c("python", " r", "sql", "tableau", "excel")

#use grepl to search the Work Experience vector for terms in CS_Term_List THEN return TRUE or FALSE
Term_TF<- grepl(paste(Term_List, collapse = '|'),Job_Hist$Work.Experience)

#add a new column to our final output dataframe that shows if the job experience matched our terms  
Final_Output<-Job_Hist
Final_Output$Term_Test <- Term_TF


#Let's see what what terms caused the TRUE Flag in the Final_Output
m<-regexpr(paste(Term_List, collapse = '|'),
       Job_Hist$Work.Experience, perl=TRUE)
T_Match <- regmatches(Job_Hist$Work.Experience,m)



#Compare Final_Output to my Desired_Output and please help me :)
Desired_T_Match <- c("NA", "sql, python, r", "tableau, excel", "NA")
Desired_Output <- data.frame(`Job Title`, `Work Experience`, Term_TF, Desired_T_Match)

#I need 2 things. 
 #1) a way to tie T_Match back to Final_Output... something like if, TRUE then match
 #2) a way to return every term matched in a coma delimited string. Example: research analyst   analyzed data...    TRUE    sql, python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_extract_all` to get a list of matches from each row:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

Job_Hist$matches <- str_extract_all(Job_Hist$Work.Experience, 
  paste(Term_List, collapse = '|'), simplify = TRUE)

                                                                      Work.Experience  Term matches.1 matches.2
1                                               cooked food; cleaned house; made beds FALSE                    
2                             analyzed data; identified gaps; used sql, python, and r  TRUE       sql    python
3 used tableau to make dashboards for clients; applied advanced macro excel functions  TRUE   tableau     excel
4                 financial planning and strategy; consulted with leaders and clients FALSE                    
  matches.3
1          
2         r
3          
4
```

**Edit:** if you'd rather have matches in one column as a comma separated string, you can use:

```
str_extract_all(Job_Hist$Work.Experience, paste(Term_List, collapse = '|')) %>% 
  sapply(., paste, collapse = ", ")

           matches
1                
2 sql, python,  r
3  tableau, excel
4
```

Note that if you use the default argument `simplify = FALSE` in `str_extract_all`, your column `matches` will look correct, like the result we get with `sapply` above. However, if you inspect with `str()` you'd see each element is actually it's own list, which will cause problems for some types of analysis.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. I spent so much time trying to figure this out and really appreciate the help.